# JOIN Problems with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, outer-join

I have table (`user_page_cells`) displayed with the following query:

```
SELECT tag_id, nid 
FROM user_page_cells WHERE nid = 1;
```

It gives me the results:

[image]

I also have a table (`graph_tags`):

```
SELECT * 
FROM graph_tags where page_node = 1
```

which gives me the results:

[image].

`user_page_cells.nid` and `graph_tags.page_node` both reference page nodes.

I need a query that will display my first query results

```
(SELECT tag_id, nid FROM user_page_cells WHERE nid = 1;)
```

with one extra column. This column needs to have the `default_graph_tag_id` from the second table (`graph_tags`) if `nid = page_node` or a `NULL` at all if it doesn't.

I have tried using `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `FULL OUTER JOIN` but I cannot get the results I am looking for.

Here is an example of the query I thought would work.

```
SELECT user_page_cells.tag_id, graph_tags.default_graph_tag_id
FROM user_page_cells
LEFT OUTER JOIN graph_tags ON user_page_cells.nid = graph_tags.page_node
WHERE user_page_cells.nid = 1.
```

I always get this no matter if `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, or `FULL` is used;

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: what's wrong with the results you are getting?

Comment: What is wrong in your output?

Comment: i want the results to look like the results from the first query.  But with another field that has the graph_tag_id displayed if the tag_id's match in the 2 tables.

Comment: So there would be 17 rows but only 5 of them would have anything in the 3rd column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to include tag_id in your join, if I understand what you want.

```
SELECT user_page_cells.tag_id, graph_tags.default_graph_tag_id
FROM user_page_cells
Left OUTER JOIN graph_tags
ON user_page_cells.nid = graph_tags.page_node
and user_page_cells.tag_id=graph_tags.tag_id
where user_page_cells.nid = 1
```